# How can i send firebase getIdToken with axios in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios, firebase-authentication

I am using the following code to obtain a user idtoken and i can succesfully log it to the console using console.log:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {  
           console.log("IDTOKEN:",idToken); 

          });
    }
});
```

I am now trying to send the token as a header in a request using axios like this:

```
async updatebalance() {
  let id = this.props.id;
  if (id === null || id === undefined) {
    id = "test";
  }
  var res = await axios.post(backUrl + "account/user_load_balance", {
    uid: localStorage.getItem("account-info"),
    id: id,
    idToken
  });
  if (res.data !== null && res.data.status && res.data.balance !== null && res.data.balance !== []) {
    this.props.dispatch(etherBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[0]));
    this.props.dispatch(tokenBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[1]));
  }
  this.setState({
    showbuttonFlag: true
  });
  this.reset_values();
}
```

however i get the following error:

> 'idToken' is not defined

I think i may need to set this as a global variable so it can be used in different function but i don't know how. How can i achieve this?

Solution 1:

```
async updatebalance() {
        let id = this.props.id;
        if (id === null || id === undefined) {
            id = "test";
        }
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
if (user) {
  const idToken = await user.getIdToken();
  var res = await axios.post(backUrl + "account/user_load_balance", {
    uid: localStorage.getItem("account-info"),
    id: id,
    idToken
  });

} else {
  console.log("User not logged in")
}
        if (res.data !== null && res.data.status && res.data.balance !== null && res.data.balance !== []) {
            this.props.dispatch(etherBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[0]));
            this.props.dispatch(tokenBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[1]));
        }
        this.setState({ showbuttonFlag: true });
        this.reset_values();
    }

    reset_values() {
        this.setState({ ethAmount: "" });
        this.setState({ sellethAmount: "" });
        this.setState({ ethPrice: "" });
        this.setState({ sellethPrice: "" });
        this.setState({ methAmount: "" });
        this.setState({ methPrice: "" });
        this.setState({ msellethAmount: "" });
        this.setState({ msellethPrice: "" });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getIdToken()` right before the Axios request and pass it as shown below:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser

if (user) {
  // user logged in
  const idToken = await user.getIdToken()

  var res = await axios.post(backUrl + "account/user_load_balance", {
    uid: localStorage.getItem("account-info"),
    id: id,
    idToken
  });

  if (res.data !== null && res.data.status && res.data.balance !== null && res.data.balance !== []) {
    this.props.dispatch(etherBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[0]));
    this.props.dispatch(tokenBalanceLoaded(res.data.balance[1]));
  }
  this.setState({
    showbuttonFlag: true
  });
  this.reset_values();

} else {
  console.log("User not logged in")
}
```

Comment: thanks i have tried this but the error is now: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res is undefined

Comment: @adminadmin make sure all of the code is inside the `if` block. I doubt if you have the dispatch things after else? Updated the answer with same.

Comment: i have updated question with your solution

Comment: That's not my solution @adminadmin. I have all the logic in the `if` block. Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: thanks very much all is working. Is this method good for production environment, because now firebase token will be obtained before each request. and if multiple requests this could slow down the application? as opposed to if the idtoken was a global variable it would need to be obained once. what is your thoughts?

Comment: @adminadmin you could implement your own caching if you want to or store the token in global state. But then you'll have to manually keep it updated as it expires every hour. The `getIdToken()` makes sure returns same token everytime but will refresh it automatically under the hood if expired.